# Magento 2 $transport->sendMessage() - where I can get the function body

Tags: magento2, email

In : `\vendor\magento\module-contact\Model\Mail.php::$transport->sendMessage();`

Where I can get the function `sendMessage()` body?

Mail is not sending from my magento.

Answer (score 0):

`Magento\Email\Model\Transport::sendMessage`
located here: `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php`

but if you may explain a bit more about the problem that mails are not sending, 
people here  could help you further.

Comment: I put an echo with exit to check that but it doesn't go to this function. is there any way to bypass this function? the magento I am working with has some 3rd party extension installed.

Comment: Yes the main function can be bypassed if any around or before plugin is made or if the class has been overridden. check for the class name in di.xml of 3rd party modules in your project.

Comment: if there is an override for that class or function, it doesn't necessarily need to be a preference or other (f.e. by around-plugins) on the `Magento\Email\Model\Transport` class directly, but could also be a preference on `Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface`. (The core preference for the interface is defined in `module-email/etc/di.xml`) Keep that in mind if you check for the class name to find overrides.